# Add barcode in Form Fillable PDF

Tags: php

I have implemented following code which fills the fields within PDF. I am using http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script93.php for filling PDF form.

Now i want to add the barcode in to pdf. For creating barcode i am using https://github.com/davidscotttufts/php-barcode/.

```
  <?php 

  require('fpdm.php'); 

  $useName = "User-Name";
  $barCode = '<img alt="testing" src="barcode.php?text='.$useName.'" />';

  $fields = array(
'name'    => 'UserName',
'address' => 'Address Here',
'city'    => 'City Here',
'phone'   => '999999999'
  );


 $pdf = new FPDM('userFormPdf.pdf'); 
 $pdf->Load($fields, false);  
 $pdf->Merge(); 
 $pdf->Output();

 ?>
```

I just want to add the barcode in pdf file. Does any one have idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to link bellow :

http://www.asudahlah.com/2018/04/how-to-add-barcode-to-pdf-created-with.html